# if statement always being skipped

Tags: if-statement, go, input

I'm trying to make a basic little banking program to get my bearing with Go. I run the program and when I type in my answer for either of the if statements, the program just moves on. Any solutions?

here's my code:

```
package main
import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Enter your name: ")
    name, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    fmt.Print("Hello ", name)
    balance := 0
    fmt.Print("Do you want to deposite? (y/n) ")
    doDeposite, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    if strings.TrimRight(doDeposite, "\n") == "y" {
        fmt.Print("How much would you like to deposite? ")
        depositeAmount, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
        da, _ := strconv.Atoi(depositeAmount)
        balance += balance + da
        fmt.Print("Your balance is ", balance)
    } else {
        fmt.Print("Would you like to withdraw?(y/n) ")
        doWithdraw, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
        if strings.TrimRight(doWithdraw, "\n") == "y" {
            fmt.Print("How much would you like to withdraw? ")
            withdrawAmount, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
            wa, _ := strconv.Atoi(withdrawAmount)
            balance += balance + wa
            fmt.Print("Your balance is ", balance)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't ignore errors! What is the actual value of `doDeposite`?

Comment: What do you expect it to do? You forgot to trim depositeAmount at least.

Comment: The lines with `+=` are likely wrong. I suspect you wanted `balance += da` / `balance += wa`.

Answer (score 3):

try to use  ReadLine() method instead of ReadString()

the doc say

> ReadLine tries to return a single line, **not including** the end-of-line bytes.
>
> ReadString reads until the first occurrence of delim in the input, returning a string containing the data up to and **including** the delimiter

Here is the updated `deposit` code for reference:

```
[...]
    fmt.Print("How much would you like to deposit? ")
    depositAmount, _, err := reader.ReadLine()
    if err != nil {
      fmt.Printf("ReadLine() error: '%s'", err)
    }
    da, err := strconv.Atoi(string(depositAmount))
    if err != nil {
      fmt.Printf("strconv error: '%s'", err)
    }
    balance += balance + da
    fmt.Print("Your balance is ", balance)
[...]
```

Alternatively, you could trim based on which OS are you executing your code.

```
if runtime.GOOS == "windows" {
  input = strings.TrimRight(input, "\r\n")
} else {
  input = strings.TrimRight(input, "\n")
}
```

Comment: Your code is still using `ReadString()` methods, whereas I suspect you meant to use `ReadLine()`. I'd probably recommend using `bufio.Scanner()` type, anyway.